# Model class not found

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying out cakePHP so I have a very simple site.  I get the following error.

class Tag extends AppModel { $name = 'Tag'; }
Fatal error: Class 'Tag' not found in /home/downtown/public_html/test_cake/cake/libs/class_registry.php on line 140

in ..\app\models\tag.php I have

`class Tag extends AppModel
{
    $name = 'Tag';
}`

What silly blunder am I making?
I have tried clearing tmp/cache and I have reloaded cakePHP from scratch.
I have seen this error in Google searches but it was a relatively obvious syntax error.

The cakephp answer system is not sending me a confirmation email so I have to ask this question here.

Comment: What's on line 140 of `/home/downtown/public_html/test_cake/cake/libs/class_registry.php`?

Comment: class_registry.php is an internal CakePHP file, handling classes in general, as the path might show.

Comment: The line in question is:
${$class} =& new $class($settings);

Comment: @Jim, which actually has nothing to do with the "real" error, it is just the first line of code, which mocks about something went wrong before. As I explained below, there are currently 2 possibilities which seem to be the most logical once.
The 'var', even if deprecated, indicates the $name variable as class var, without it is just a "normal" varibale.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, it was dumb.

Missing  tags at the beginning and end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

It might be, that "tag" is a reserved word in CakePHP, try to use another class name, and report if you get this error again.

**My recommendation:**

- **cakephp on google groups**

**Suggestion:**

*Use:*

```
var $name = 'Tag';
```

*instead of*

```
$name = 'Tag';
```

Comment: I get the same error on another model with the class name "Note".

Comment: Did you tryed my suggestion? Use something more abstract, and in fully lowercase, e.g. 'pencil'

Comment: Just to clear that up, I did create a table called pencils and a class called Pencil and got the same error.  The leading upper case char is a requirement of the cakePHP naming conventions.

Also cakephp on Google croups is closed.

Comment: I can send you an invitation, I never recognized CakePHP on google groups as closed, I think it is still open, I visited the site today.

Answer (score -1):

The problem must be that you have not declared the model with the same name. Try looking at your model and certify that the names are equal. If you change the name of the model, the error is the same you are explaining here.